# Biwavelet: obtain correlation from coherence analysis

Tags: r, correlation, biwavelet

I'm using the biwavelet package in R for wavelet coherency analysis. I'm interested in obtaining the correlation (rsq) between the two time series at every time step. I am using the

```
 wtc.obj$rsq
```

command, which returns a matrix with columns equal to the number of time steps in my time series, but 35 rows. I'm unsure what each row indicates, or how to interpret this matrix. Any help would be appreciated.

```
wtc.obj <- wtc(cbind(seq(1,10,1),log(out_temp)), cbind(seq(1,10,1),water_temp), nrands=300)
```

EDIT:
data from dput 
time series 1 (first 10 rows) - I log transform when running the wtc function

```
out_temp <- c(16733551588.5339, 16870453377.5994, 16772151897.9109, 16728321668.6624, 
18436978257.3136, 16846726183.718, 16726205228.4934, 15864317293.7725, 
17741474399.0609, 16737589895.4835)
```

time series 2 (first 10 rows)

```
water_temp <- c(4.91, 4.65, 4.85, 7.28, 3.21, 3.03, 2.33, 3.61, 4.75, 2.99)
```

The rsq matrix from that subset

```
structure(c(0.88811122950383, 0.883005701601978, 0.878120064019507, 
0.871218670458293, 0.862871890404607, 0.849780856651561, 0.840171059917514, 
0.829232598943086, 0.811227300687161, 0.796653906504197, 0.878693836960343, 
0.872034301656082, 0.866106223420483, 0.859558992869246, 0.852443544668167, 
0.840184634073849, 0.827708800659723, 0.811408370380922, 0.788425832549514, 
0.772792192041626, 0.855370796300556, 0.843632447822571, 0.83347989490027, 
0.82502778304639, 0.817143933084284, 0.803518294348461, 0.786136691605393, 
0.762216446396908, 0.734098629192821, 0.720678074329317, 0.820886442250837, 
0.801007780631502, 0.783872172267905, 0.771785540072379, 0.761925141232704, 
0.745772620239666, 0.722008778765105, 0.688727955307826, 0.656285165868401, 
0.649397618795314, 0.778783676688075, 0.748508440655847, 0.722221842446535, 
0.705146362196499, 0.692592835090724, 0.673639897529668, 0.642806785244917, 
0.599135162886376, 0.563562916220616, 0.567083941737865, 0.73879043910938, 
0.698067627624491, 0.662173684644483, 0.639492210729284, 0.624029985615804, 
0.602844549692042, 0.565448685551128, 0.511410316678153, 0.472697038937781, 
0.486799890264125, 0.714442234122642, 0.666418315719431, 0.623191992054625, 
0.595588030567084, 0.577735144515651, 0.555785176155343, 0.514039160319749, 
0.451499228449641, 0.407768394703545, 0.426752291137762, 0.714297446948971, 
0.66420238067957, 0.618056304220161, 0.587592642193242, 0.568708099912014, 
0.548156040715463, 0.505870129160218, 0.439211545851626, 0.388914491010902, 
0.403664274336693, 0.735670285655772, 0.688140502032425, 0.643438413055784, 
0.612663235117296, 0.594432527004536, 0.577262471111257, 0.53845986672713, 
0.473628467143225, 0.418475083414332, 0.42245896430964, 0.767160302402965, 
0.724247590757992, 0.683226594941654, 0.653695114654581, 0.636935449729284, 
0.623530143950479, 0.590354098223849, 0.532020189464932, 0.476482045338038, 
0.46930594464708), .Dim = c(10L, 10L))
```

Comment: would you mind adding your dataset (using dput(yourdataset) ) so we can run your code and have a look at the output?

Comment: In addition to adding a sample of your data, please also include all the code necessary to create `wtc.obj`.

Comment: Your code still isn't [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What are `out_temp` and `water_temp`? Please provide *all* the data and code needed to reproduce the issue you're grappling with so that we can focus on solving your specific problem, rather than spending time trying to figure out what you've done already. If your data are too large to post, then provide a smaller sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @eipi10 It should be now. The output displayed about for time series 1 is out_temp and for time series 2 is water_temp. I hope that helps.